# Command Line Arguments in C Returning Large Numbers

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I am writing a basic program to calculate an arithmetic-geometric mean using command line arguments using C. However the program doesn't seem to be recognizing anything I type in. Here is my code:

```
/*
*This program will calculate an arithmetic-geometric mean
*provided two numbers (x,y) and an epsilon (e) are entered.
*/

#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    //Check for command line argument.
    if (argc != 4) {
        printf ("Please enter two numbers (x,y) and an epsilon (e)\n");
        printf ("as command line arguments for an AGM calculation\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    double e,x,y,an,gn;

    x = atof (argv[1]); //First number x.
    y = atof (argv[2]); //Second number y.
    e = atof (argv[3]); //Number of repetitions e.

    double absoluteAnMinusGn; //Continuation condition.
    double a = (x + y) / 2; //Normal arithmetic mean.
    double g = sqrt (x * y); //Normal geometric mean.

    an = (a + g) / 2; //Iteration 1 for calculation arithmetic mean.
    gn = sqrt (a * g); //Iteration 1 for calculation geometric mean.
    absoluteAnMinusGn = an - gn; //Calculates continuation condition.
       if (absoluteAnMinusGn < 0) {
           absoluteAnMinusGn = absoluteAnMinusGn * (-1); //Ensures absolute value of continuation condition.
        }

    printf ("DEBUG IN: x%d, y%d, e%d, absoulteAnMinusGn%d, a%d, g%d, an%d, gn%d\n", x,y,e,absoluteAnMinusGn,a,g,an,gn);//DEBUG CODE 

    while (absoluteAnMinusGn > e) {
        an = (a + g) / 2;
        gn = sqrt (a * g);
        a = an;
        g = gn;
        absoluteAnMinusGn = an - gn;
        if (absoluteAnMinusGn < 0) {
            absoluteAnMinusGn = absoluteAnMinusGn * (-1);
        }
    }

    //printf ("The arithmetric-geometric mean is (%d,%d) for %d\n", a,g,e); 
            printf ("DEBUG OUT: x%d, y%d, e%d, absoulteAnMinusGn%d, a%d, g%d, an%d, gn%d\n", x,y,e,absoluteAnMinusGn,a,g,an,gn);//DEBUG CODE 

    return 0;
}
```

I enter the following on the command line: agm.exe 3 4 5

I get the following output:

```
DEBUG IN: x0, y10742661112, e0, absoluteANMinusGn1074790400, a0, g1075052544, an-171951648, gn1057505593

DEBUG OUT: x0, y10742661112, e0, absoluteANMinusGn1074790400, a0, g1075052544, an-171951648, gn1057505593
```

I made a similar program yesterday for calculating an integral using command line inputs that works exactly as intended. The code for that is here:

```
/*
*This program will calculate a Riemann sum using the 
*left hand rule for sin(x)/x.
*/

#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    //Check for command line argument.
    if (argc != 4) {
        printf ("Please enter integral bounds (a,b) and number of intervals (n)\n");
        printf ("as command line arguments for a Riemann sum calculation \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    double a,b,i,n,h,riemann,rectangles,answer;

    a = atof (argv[1]); //Lower bound of integral.
    b = atof (argv[2]); //Upper bound of integral.
    n = atof (argv[3]); //Number of intervals.

    h = (b - a) / n; //Delta X.
    i = 0; //Counts intervals.

    //Calculation of Left Hand Riemann Sum.
    while (i <= (n - 1)) {
        if (a == 0 && i == 0) { //Stops from dividing by zero.
            rectangles = 1;
            i++;
        }
        riemann = (sin(a + (i * h))) / (a + (i * h));
        rectangles += riemann;
        i++;
    }
    //Finalize answer.
    answer = rectangles * h;

    printf ("Sin(x)/x for bounds (%f , %f) with %f intervals is approximately %f \n", a,b,n,answer);

    return 0;
}
```

The above program for a left hand Riemann sum outputs correctly, and is almost the same as the code I have for the AGM. Can someone please help me figure out what is going wrong here? I've searched all over and I can't find a solution. I'm aware that the AGM code is probably set up to output an incorrect answer, but my primary concern is fixing my command line argument recognition. I can redo my math later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format specifier for printing double is `%f`. In cases where you didn't provide the right format specifier to process the double, and passed double to `%d` format specifier - it lead to undefined behavior.(`%d` expect integral argument not double) (in your case wrong output).

From §[7.21.6.3p9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9) N1570 (c11 standard)

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Thank you, I see my mistake now. I have brought dishonor upon my house, and my cow.

Answer (score 0):

**Just replace** the `%d`(which is a format specifier for integers) with `%f`(which is the format specifier for double) because you are using a variable of type double, not an integer .

Answer (score 0):

I did not test your algorithm, but I found at least three problems in your code. I now list them as follows:

1. Forgot init your variable, that's why you got a `Large Numbers`
    which is memory undefined data!
2. No have covert your argv to a integer type.
3. Wrong format for `printf`.

I have put my fixed code here, you can test it . if it can run as your expect!

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 4) {
        printf ("Please enter two numbers (x,y) and an epsilon (e)\n");
        printf ("as command line arguments for an AGM calculation\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //  argv is pointer which pointer to pointer 
    // and argv[1] is a pointer to a string.
    // so we need to covert string to int
    char *p=NULL;
    int x = strtol(argv[1], &p, 10);
    int y = strtol(argv[2], &p, 10);
    int e = strtol(argv[3], &p, 10);

    //Check for command line argument.

    double an = 0.0,gn =0.0;


    double absoluteAnMinusGn=0.0; //Continuation condition.
    double a = (x + y) / 2; //Normal arithmetic mean.
    double g = sqrt (x * y); //Normal geometric mean.

    an = (a + g) / 2; //Iteration 1 for calculation arithmetic mean.
    gn = sqrt (a * g); //Iteration 1 for calculation geometric mean.
    absoluteAnMinusGn = an - gn; //Calculates continuation condition.
       if (absoluteAnMinusGn < 0) {
           absoluteAnMinusGn = absoluteAnMinusGn * (-1); //Ensures absolute value of continuation condition.
        }

    printf ("DEBUG IN: x%d, y%d, e%d, absoulteAnMinusGn=%f, a=%f, g=%f, an=%f, gn=%f\n", x,y,e,absoluteAnMinusGn,a,g,an,gn);//DEBUG CODE 

    while (absoluteAnMinusGn > e) {
        an = (a + g) / 2;
        gn = sqrt (a * g);
        a = an;
        g = gn;
        absoluteAnMinusGn = an - gn;
        if (absoluteAnMinusGn < 0) {
            absoluteAnMinusGn = absoluteAnMinusGn * (-1);
        }
    }

    printf ("DEBUG OUT: x=%d, y=%d, e=%d, absoulteAnMinusGn=%f, a=%f, g=%f, an=%f, gn=%f\n", x,y,e,absoluteAnMinusGn,a,g,an,gn);//DEBUG CODE 
    return 0;
}
```

and then when i run it with some sample number like below show, i got the result .
[image: Running result]